# Bitcoin transfer missing

Tags: transactions, crypto.com

I transferred $100 from my Crypto.com wallet to my blockchain.com only for blockchain.com to say it was never received. Here is the transaction Id
c8b7d7b-01e9-4009-be27-
b23bdabb64b0
What can I do

Comment: That isn't a Bitcoin transaction-ID. It might be a proprietary wallet-ID - but those mean nothing in the Bitcoin network. You probably need to resolve this directly with the two businesses.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this is not a Bitcoin TXID. Contact Crypto.com support [here](https://help.crypto.com/en)